# How to use the values of one column from the select statement to display a column from a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my current `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [QVD/CSV Names] AS 'CSV/Excel Files',
                [SourceTypeID],
                CASE 
                    WHEN substring([QVD/CSV Names], len([QVD/CSV Names]) - 3, 4) = '.csv'   THEN 'CSV'
                    WHEN substring([QVD/CSV Names], len([QVD/CSV Names]) - 3, 4) = '.xls'   THEN 'Excel'
                    WHEN substring([QVD/CSV Names], len([QVD/CSV Names]) - 4, 5) = '.xlsx' THEN 'Excel'
                END
                AS [Source Types]
FROM STG_QVDs
LEFT OUTER JOIN SourceTypes AS c
    ON  [Source Types] = c.[SourceTypeName]
WHERE [QVD/CSV Names] IS NOT NULL
    AND substring([QVD/CSV Names], len([QVD/CSV Names]) - 3, 4) <> '.qvd'
```

Right now, I have three columns. One column would display the name of the files, `CSV/Excel Files`. Another is suppose to display the ID of the source (which I am generating on the spot in another column using the case statement). Since the column isn't in the database, I had to create it there and this is where I'm stuck. I do not want to display the `[Source Types]` column. I just want `CSV/Excel Files` and `SourceTypeID`. Is there a way for me to be able to display the appropriate ID for the rows using that generated column?

This is how it looks in the SourceTypes lookup table.

```
SourceTypeID    SourceTypeName
------------    --------------
      1              CSV
      2              Excel
```

This is what it displays:

```
CSV/Excel Files    Source Types
---------------    ------------
   file1.csv          CSV
   file2.xls          Excel
```

I want it to display:

```
CSV/Excel Files    SourceTypeID
---------------    ------------
   file1.csv          1
   file2.xls          2
```

Comment: Which kind of SQL is this? SQLite? MySQL?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.  If you don't want to display the column, then just remove it.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue, sorry, I tagged it now. It's SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare `CSV / Excel` values first in a CTE (Common Table Expression) and then join them to lookup table. Something like this.

```
;with names as ( -- start CTE
SELECT DISTINCT [QVD/CSV Names] AS [CSV/Excel Files],
                CASE --"ends with"
                    WHEN [QVD/CSV Names] like '%.csv'  THEN 'CSV'
                    WHEN [QVD/CSV Names] like '%.xls'  THEN 'Excel'
                    WHEN [QVD/CSV Names] like '%.xlsx' THEN 'Excel'
                END
                AS [Source Types]
FROM STG_QVDs
WHERE [QVD/CSV Names] IS NOT NULL
    AND [QVD/CSV Names] not like '%.qvd'
) --end CTE
select names.[CSV/Excel Files], c.[SourceTypeID]
from names
LEFT OUTER JOIN SourceTypes AS c
    ON  names.[Source Types] = c.[SourceTypeName]
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with a modified version of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work, because it attempts to reference a column alias in the `ON` clause.  Well, it might compile and run if `[Source Types]` is already defined in one of the tables; but the code probably won't do what you intend.

I think you intend:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [QVD/CSV Names] AS [CSV/Excel Files],
                [SourceTypeID],
FROM STG_QVDs LEFT OUTER JOIN
     SourceTypes c
     ON [QVD/CSV Names] LIKE '%.' + c.[SourceTypeName]
WHERE [QVD/CSV Names] IS NOT NULL AND
      [QVD/CSV Names] NOT LIKE '%.qvd';
```

Note:  The `SELECT DISTINCT` is suspicious.  You may not need it at all.

Comment: It doesn't work as well when the file type is '.xls' or '.xlsx'.

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine but your instinct to alias and use the alias is smart as it can make the code easier to read.  You can create a derived table or a CTE, use the alias for that column and then outside of the derived table/CTE, you can refer to it using the alias.